# How can I filter a group-by query by an aggregate function ?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

How can I only display results which have a budget > 1000 ?

```
SELECT 
     BP_Year
    ,BP_UID
    ,BP_Name
    ,SUM(BP_Budget) as sumBudget  
FROM T_UPS_BudgetPositions 

GROUP BY 
     BP_UID 
    ,BP_Name
    ,BP_Year
```

Comment: use `having` to filter the aggregated value

Comment: I really am interested as to how this question got voted so high. Putting the post title into Google gets you the answer within the first 5 results.

Answer (score 4):

By using the HAVING-clause:

```
SELECT 
     BP_Year
    ,BP_UID
    ,BP_Name
    ,SUM(BP_Budget) as sumBudget  
FROM T_UPS_BudgetPositions 

GROUP BY 
     BP_UID 
    ,BP_Name
    ,BP_Year

HAVING SUM(BP_Budget) > 1000
```